# Android RadioButton CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener Error

Tags: java, android, colors

I have a question for my code, it should change the background color of my Start-Activity. I should choose between blue and red with radio buttons (in Radiogroup). I always get this error:

> Error:(8, 8) error: com.example.clecks.reaction_game.OnCheckedChangeListener is not abstract and does not override abstract method onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton,boolean) in android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener
>   C:\Users\clecks\Desktop\asdfasdf\app\src\main\java\com\example\clecks\reaction_game\OnCheckedChangeListener.java

When I click on the error message there opens a new class named 
`OnCheckedChangeListener.java` :

```
public class OnCheckedChangeListener implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {}
```

Here is my code:

```
public class activity_settings extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_settings);
    colorchange();
}

public void colorchange() {
    final RelativeLayout background = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.start);
    final RadioButton changeToBlue = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.button_blue);
    final RadioButton changeToRed = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.button_red);


    final Button button_save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_save);
    button_save.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            changeOption(background);
        }
    });


    changeToBlue.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            changeToBlue(background);
        }
    });

    changeToRed.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            changeToRed(background);
        }

    });


}

public void changeOption(RelativeLayout background) {
    if (background.isEnabled()) {
        background.setEnabled(false);
    } else {
        background.setEnabled(true);

    }
}

public void changeToBlue(RelativeLayout background) {
    background.setBackgroundColor(0x0000FF00);
    background.invalidate();

}
public void changeToRed(RelativeLayout background) {
    background.setBackgroundColor(0x0000FF00);
    background.invalidate();

}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_activity_settings, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}}
```

Comment: Why the error is complaining about `com.example.clecks.reaction_game.OnCheckedChangeListener `? What is it? And in such case, what is `activity_settings`?

Comment: activity_settings is my activity for my settings-menue for the game, where i can choose background and sound. mhmm...I don´t know, I deleted com.example.clecks.reaction_game.OnCheckedChangeListener and now i can run it, but there is a new error, i will update...

Comment: Means you had the error I helped you fixed in another class `com.example.clecks.reaction_game.OnCheckedChangeListener`. Now `activity_settings` is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CompoundButton](http://CompoundButton) itself is an abstract class (extending `Button).

You should not have `CompoundButton` in your *activity_activity_settings* layout.

Use `Button` for example instead.

Comment: I don´t have any CompoundButtons in my Layout - they are all RadioButtons

Comment: Then do *not* use `CompoundButtons` in your code, but use `RadioButtons` instead. Why did you use the wrong type?

Comment: i have, but same Error with (I´m standin on the line Oo):         changeToBlue.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                changeToBlue(background);
            }
        });

Comment: Please update your question. The error message *cannot* be exactly the same since you changed classes...

Comment: Error:(8, 8) error: com.example.clecks.reaction_game.OnCheckedChangeListener is not abstract and does not override abstract method onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton,boolean) in android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener
C:\Users\clecks\Desktop\asdfasdf\app\src\main\java\com\example\clecks\reaction_game\OnCheckedChangeListener.java

Comment: Update your (question's) code since I made you change it... This is getting hard to follow you know. Update the exact code and error please, by editing your quesiton.

Comment: ah sorry... is up2date now